# Git: Work on merged branch, which was unmerged afterwards

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I am having the following problem:
I worked on a branch A. 
Branch A was merged into the Master branch, so far so fine.

After some time, the customer decided, to undo the changed, done in Branch A on the Master branch, because it has to be updated.

So the history in the Master branch looks like :

```
Some stuff
Some other stuff
Some stuff, where the merge of Branch A was reverted
Some other stuff
Some other stuff
Branch A was merged into master
The commit of Branch A (Branch A contains one Commit)
```

I want to rebase Branch A, so I want something like:

```
The commit of Branch A (From here I want to continue working)
Some stuff
Some other stuff
Some stuff, where the merge of Branch A was reverted
Some other stuff
Some other stuff
Branch A was merged into master
The commit of Branch A (Branch A contains one Commit)
```

Note that I don´t want to change the history of my remote master, I need the commit of Branch A to be rebases on the last commits of my master. Then I want to push my updated Branch A to Master again.

Now I want to continue working on Branch A, but first I want to rebase Branch A on the current master branch, to have the newest state.

The problem is now: When I rebase my Branch A on master, git seems to delete the changed I did in Branch A. I think this is because of the merge reverse in the Master branch. So: Git sees, that Branch A was deleted in the master branch, so when I rebase Branch A on master, the deletion will be done too.

I don´t want to copy the files I changed in Branch A one after one on another Branch, which was checkout out of master. I think there is a better solution, any recommendations?

Comment: What, _exactly_, did the customer do? Did he _revert_ the merge commit, or delete it with a `rebase`? The answer that one will determine the best course of action.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz The given history shows that there is a revert commit.

Comment: Why not just revert the revert on Branch A after merging (not rebasing) `master` onto it?

Comment: There is a commit, which just reverted the merge of Branch A. Revert the revert sounds good, but what happens, when Branch A is then pushed again to our remote Master again, where I have no access to. I think the changes in Branch A are deleted again, but my new changes will be set on top, did I understand that correct?

Comment: Can you clarify which commit `master` points to and which one `branch-a` points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `git checkout branch-a && git rebase -i master`, you will get a list of commits in your text editor with the `pick` command in front of each. You can change this to one of several options, all of which are explained in the given text. For example, you can `skip` the revert commit and those changes will not be reverted.

Another potential solution is to rebase as you have then `git revert` the commit which reverted the merge of `branch-a`.

Comment: Sounds pretty cool, but I understand it correctly, that for this, I need access to our remote master?

Or when I do this on my local master branch, and I continue working on this branch. What happens when I push it again to our remote master since the revert commit is still in the history?

Comment: @MJohnyJ Note that you can make any changes you wish to your local repository without access to any remote branches. The suggestion here is for rebasing your `branch-a`. I wrote this on some assumptions about where `master` and `branch-a` point, which I now think were incorrect. Will you please clarify where these branches are?

Comment: @MJohnyJ `git rebase -i` will allow you to remove the revert commit. You may need to modify the final argument and even use `--onto`. You can even revert the revert commit to get the changes back.

Comment: Reverting the revert did the job for me! It´s also logical, the history stays how it should be and pushing to the remote master should be no problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MJohnyJ Glad it worked! My original answer was based on an incorrect understanding about the state of your branches.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a bit tricky. Since the `HEAD` of your `BranchA` is already part of `master`, git considers the code in the master to be the newer one than the `BranchA`. In this case, it would have been better if you guys had reset the changes in the master branch instead of reverting them with an explicit commit.

*All of the following options involve rewriting history, so try them in some temporary branch first.*

One option is to change the master branch using `rebase --onto` such that both merge and revert commit are removed.

```
git rebase --onto <commit_id_before_merge_commit> <revert_merge_commit_id> master
```

Second is to change the commit hashes in `BranchA` such that git won't recognize them the same as in master.

```
git checkout BranchA
git reset HEAD^n # n is the number of commits that are exclusive to branchA
git add -u # Add all the files. Make sure to add newly created ones.
git commit -m 'some message'
git rebase master # should work now
```

Thirdly, you can also use interactive rebasing to change the commit ids in the `BranchA`

```
git rebase -i <first_exclusive_initial_commit_id_of_branchA>
```

Comment: Changing the commit hash seems to be a really good idea. It's the only way I can see, without having access to our remote master repo. Not sure though, if it is a proper solution for the problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to touch the history of master, you need to reapply your changes to the top of master, ignoring the fact that they were already applied and reverted. Depending on the exact nature of the reverting commit, lets call it `<revert>`, I see exactly two ways to accomplish this:

1. If `<revert>` *only* undid your changes, then you can just revert it again to get a commit that reapplies your changes (think `--x == x`).
2. If the reverting commit is not pure, I would approach this situation like this:

   - Create a patch sequence for your branch with `git format-patch`.
   - Apply this patch sequence to master with `git am`.

   The point is, that `git am` is agnostic of history: It only looks at the current commit's state and applies the patches to that.